# GWT, Vaadin ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, gwt, concurrency, vaadin

I have a legacy application implemented using GWT, Vaadin, Icepush.

The problem is that sometimes I get an error after clicking on a button.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.getDirtyVisibleComponents(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1907)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.writeUidlResponce(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:894)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.paintAfterVariableChanges(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:839)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:765)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:296)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:483)
    at org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet.service(ICEPushServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As you can see this happens implicitly, I have tried to debug the app, but haven't reproduced this error.

Please suggest what can be wrong ?

I would be grateful for any help.

P.S. I am using Vaadin 6.5

Comment: I hope you are using a collection and an Iterartor to manipulate it, and during some part of iterartion, you are adding data to list. This usually causes ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: No, I am not using any collection with an iterator

Comment: I guess this happens while pushing UI changes to the browser. Probably you need to lock the UI while doing the Push.